# angular I can only able to set 'true` on `ng-if` but i can't set `false'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-ng-click, event-propagation

I am trying to use the `ng-if` for opening and closing.

I am able to only set the value to `true` to show the child, but I'm not able to set the value back to `false`.

Here is my code :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

var array = [{'name':'one'}, {'name':'two'}, {'name':'three'}];

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = array;
    $scope.showChild = function ( obj ) {
        obj.show = true;
    }
    $scope.closeChild = function ( n ) {
        n.show = false;
    }
});
```

html :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in names" ng-click="showChild(n)">
        {{n.name}}
        <h2 ng-if="n.show">
            {{n.name | uppercase }}
        </h2> 
        <span ng-click="closeChild(n)">
            Close
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/htzpM2Rn6Z7drc9OdR29?p=preview)

Comment: IF it's only about show/hide, there is a much neater way to do the same logic using ``ng-show`` & ``ng-click`` without defining anything in the controller yourself - http://jsfiddle.net/cxxwgnh6/ The trick is that ``ng-show="showAdditionalInfo"`` and ``ng-click="showAdditionalInfo = !showAdditionalInfo``. Angular will define the scope variables itself.

Comment: Close button should also be under a container with ng-if. Create a div container to the <h2> and <span> and add ng-if to the div container. with your solution the close button will stay shown after you close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This how event bubbling(Propagation of event upwards) works.

Basically this happens parent and child element both has `click` event bounded to them. When you click on the inner element it 1st call the click event of its own & then it calls parent element `click` event by bubbling up that event. This is what your problem is in your current implementation. So you need to stop propagation of event upwards by calling `stopPropagation` method on that event from `closeChild` method. For getting event object you need to pass `$event` object from the `ng-click` method which can be `$event`.

**Html**

```
     <li ng-repeat="n in names" ng-click="showChild(n)">
        {{n.name }} {{n}}
        <h2 ng-if="n.show">{{n.name | uppercase }}</h2> 
        <span ng-click="closeChild($event, n)">Close</span>
    </li>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.closeChild = function(event, n) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    n.show = false;
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rTF9dpVCcfZzg1p2letP?p=preview)

Comment: @3gwebtrain Glad to help you..Thanks. Look at the edit. I've added more explanation to it. which would help you to understand it. Thanks :)

Comment: was confused for a moment, as why was this not working. Good Spot.

Comment: @Anand Thanks for appreciation. :)

Answer (score 3):

When clicking the span-element you're also clicking it's parent li-element, so directly after the close function is run, the show function is run. Why dont you try two separate child elements to add the ng-click to:

```
<li ng-repeat="n in names">
            <span ng-click="showChild(n)">{{n.name}}</span>
            <h2 ng-if="n.show">{{n.name | uppercase }}</h2> 
            <span ng-click="closeChild(n)">Close</span>
        </li>
```

I edited your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NoBCJ9OyhQ6axc5cJXc9?p=preview) to show it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without the `showChild` controller function too:

```
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="n in names">
        <span ng-click="(n.show) ? n.show = false : n-show = true">{{n.name}}</span>
        <h2 ng-if="n.show">{{n.name | uppercase }}</h2> 
        <span ng-click="(n.show) ? n.show = false : n-show = true">Close</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: why anyone should change his html structure? rather than solving core problem by understanding it..